Calculating the expectation value of the angular momentum operator
I'm not looking for the exact answer to the question, but rather why a certain way of solving it is chosen. We agree on the answer, but why is the approach different. I'm afraid it's a sign of me not understanding it well enough or skipping corners.
If it's of any help, I'm not a physics student, rather a molecular life science student. Our treatment of quantum mechanics is not as formal as you might be used to. This might have implications for the level of detail and handwavyness. I can't judge that, so please be patient with me, I'm not trying to be obtuse, want to show the steps and work hard to get to a sufficient level of understanding. We use Atkins's Physical Chemistry.
Given some wavefunction $\psi(\phi) = \cos(\phi)$, calculate the expectation value of $\hat I $, well I simply go about it by normalizing the wave function and using that: $<I> = \int_{0}^{2\pi}\sqrt{\frac{1}{\pi}}\cos(\phi) * \hat I \sqrt{\frac{1}{\pi}}\cos(\phi) d\phi =  (\sqrt{\frac{1}{\pi}})^2\frac{\hbar}{i} \int_{0}^{2\pi}\cos(\phi) * \frac{d}{d\phi}\cos(\phi) d\phi = \frac{1}{\pi}\frac{\hbar}{i} \int_{0}^{2\pi}\cos(\phi) * \sin(\phi) d\phi$
So I get to: $\frac{1}{\pi}\frac{\hbar}{i} \frac{1}{2\phi}\sin^2{2\phi \pi}$, which evaluates to zero.
Right, then I check my work and I see a, seemingly different way to go about it, as they start their solution: $<I> = \frac{\int_{0}^{2\pi} \psi^* \hat I\psi d\phi}{\int_{0}^{2\pi} \psi^* \psi d\phi}$....
Why are they solving it this way? In the examples in the book they simple use the 'method' I'm using. Why this division between those integrals? Is it equivalent? I truly don't understand why the solve it this way.

How do come up with
$$
\frac{1}{\pi}\frac{\hbar}{i} \frac{1}{2\phi}\sin^2{2\phi \pi}?
$$
The answer for the integral must be a number, not a function of $\phi$.  The integral
$$
\int_0^{2 \pi} \cos\phi \frac{d}{d\phi} \cos\phi \,d\phi = \frac 12 \int_0^{2\pi}  \frac{d}{d\phi}(\cos^2\phi)\, d\phi=\frac 12 \left[\cos^2\phi\right]_0^{2\pi}
$$ is indeed zero though because $\cos^20= \cos^2 (2\pi)$ .
You performed  the  division by $\int \psi^*\psi d\phi$ when you normalized your wavefunction.

It was sloppy, indeed, it was meant to convey how I evaluated the integral, like you did in your edit $[\cos^2 \phi]^{2\pi}_0$
